# sqlalchemy importerror when using cron

Tags: python, cron, sqlalchemy

I've got a python script running some database tasks that I'm having trouble scheduling. It's running on a AWS EC2 with ubuntu 16.04, the anaconda2 4.4 community AMI.  I"m attempting to run M-F @ 1:30am, my crontab says:

> 30 1 * * 1,2,3,4,5 python /home/ubuntu/mydir/cronjob.py >> /home/ubuntu/logs.log 2>&1

The logs.log file shows an "ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy".  I can enter python directly from the command line, and import sqlalchemy with no error.  From the command line, I can also run:

> python /home/ubuntu/mydir/cronjob.py >> /home/ubuntu/logs.log 2>&1

which runs the file just fine.  I've seen various posts on changing python path, but nothing has hit yet. Why am I getting a different output when running the same command from cron?

Comment: are you running the second command from inside a virtual environment?

Comment: How can I tell?  >$which python returns >/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/bin/python. i'm not sure how to determine if cron is calling a different environment.

Comment: it is well explained in this post. https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working. It is mostly likely that the path of package is not specified. I had the same problem before. The problem is solved by adding the python script into a .sh file and within this .sh file add export PATH="/PathToAnaconda3/bin:$PATH" at the beginning.